# For loop equivalent for each statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pycharm

I'm looking for an alternative for this each function. Can a for loop be created in its place to still have the same effect?

```
  $(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {


      $('.fadeInBlock').each(function() {

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* Adjust the "200" to either have a delay or that the content starts fading a bit before you reach it  */
        bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window + 200;

        if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

          $(this).animate({
            'opacity': '1'
          }, 1000);

        }
      });

    });
  });
```

Reason for this is there is a problem with the IDE recognising the each function. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Its strange because this next batch of code works in the EXACT SAME file

```
$(function () {
    var text = $(".text");
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 200) {
            text.removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
            text.addClass("hidden");
        }
        if (scroll + 250 > $('.homeIm2').offset().top) { // when the div with homeIm2 class scrolls into view
            text.hide();
        }
        if (scroll + 250 < $('.homeIm2').offset().top) { // when the div with homeIm2 class scrolls into view
            text.show();
        }


    });
});
```

Comment: Your IDE recognizes all the other JQuery, but not the `each()`?! Time for a new IDE.

Comment: "*Reason for this is there is a problem with the IDE recognising the each function*" this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) then - you are better off fixing your IDE. It's a *tool*, it should serve *you*, you shouldn't serve your tools.

Comment: I'd suggest you'd be better fixing your IDE instead of lobotomising your code to fix broken syntax recognition.

Comment: I dont know how to fix it :(

Comment: Then ask a question about it, giving specific details about the editor and the error it displays, or Google it. Failing that, ignore it.

Comment: I cant find anything.... hence why im here

Comment: What is your ide ?

Comment: Voting to close as this is really more about a software issue than a programming issue.

Comment: @hsyn.ozkara Pycharm

Comment: @ScottMarcus i did ask before and no one helped so i thought id try an alternative

Comment: @Joelad try figuring out the issue with the editor until then try the below answer and let me know if that helps ?

Comment: Please check your javascript plugin.. Probably out of date or need plugin update. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7353-js-toolbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a solution to what you have asked using `for`

```
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    AllClasses = $('.fadeInBlock')
    for(var i=0; i<AllClasses.length; i++){

      var bottom_of_object = $(AllClasses[i]).position().top + $(AllClasses[i]).outerHeight();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

      /* Adjust the "200" to either have a delay or that the content starts fading a bit before you reach it  */
      bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window + 200;

      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

        $(AllClasses[i]).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 1000);

      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It didnt work unfortunately. I have no idea what the problem is. Thank you though

Comment: Oh that looks good. I tried it on https://jsfiddle.net/joel081112/9e8jdpr3/2/ and got it worked. Then have tried in my js file and got no error. Now just need to try it in my project. Thank you!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I knew this would be a good alternative to each()